# Set a custom notification layout for Fcm (Firebase cloud Messaging ) notification in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to set a custom notification layout for my fcm notification received by flutter app . I have **already created notification layout using xml** but i am having **trouble integrating it with my flutter android app** .

**Things i have done :**

1. I have read through Custom Notification by [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification)
2. Have already set up my custom_notification_layout.xml
3. Have also designed a notification handler for flutter code.

**Thing I want**

**When the fcm notification arrives , the app shows my own custom layout and behave the same way as any other notification does :**

1. opens my **Flutter** and passes **Remote Message** to

`FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage)`

Any help will be highly appreciated **Thank You** .

Comment: Could you find any solution?

Comment: used a third party package Awesome_Notifications and modified the builder according to my choice.

Comment: Do you have any example code snippet?

Comment: Sorry , its a bit complex and the code is currently commercial , try going to awesome notification's issue and discussions on github as this question is already discussed there.